# UIImageView pinch zoom within Cell using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, zooming

I would like to add a function which permits to zoom on an image.

I'm new to swift, my problem is probably stupid: I would like to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` in order to have this function.

The problem is that the image and the scrollView are within a TableViewCell. So I tried to add that delegate function in the Cell class but it did not work.

How can I do that?

```
class PhotoDetailViewControllerCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0        
        // scrollView.delegate = self - it is set on the storyboard.
    }  

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

        return imgPhoto
    }
```

If I want to call that function in the `TableViewController`, I can't return imgPhoto because the outlet is in the Cell.

Comment: But this is a UIViewController class

Comment: My fault, I edited

Comment: UITableViewCell doesn't have viewDidLoad

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-17439957-zoom-imageview-from-tableviewcell

Comment: Once again, my fault @Nitish it was awakFromNib instead

Comment: No issues. Did you check the link ?

Comment: @Nitish how to use this in swift 4? by bridging header?

Comment: @GoribDeveloper : Correct, by bridging header. But you would have to update the link code to the latest objective c syntax as well. Try that out.

Comment: Okay sir.Thank you